# Не получается отправить GET запрос через сокеты

Tags: python, сокет

```
import socket

def request(addr, data):
    r = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    r.settimeout(10)
    r.connect(addr)
    r.sendall(data)
    ret = r.recv(4096)
    r.close()
    return ret

text = """
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: wp-settings
Connection: keep-alive"""

print(request(("www.google.com", 80), text.encode()))
```

Есть вот такой код и он застревает на строке `ret = r.recv(4096)`. Не могу понять с чем это связано, подскажите что не так.

Comment: После Connection: keep-alive добавьте два переноса строки. С точки зрения веб-сервера у вас блок запроса не завершен сейчас, веб-сервер ожидает от клиента продолжения.

Comment: @insolor, благодарю, это как раз то, что было нужно

Comment: Еще по [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2) окончания строк должны быть CR LF (`\r\n`), но в данном случае почему-то сработало и просто с `\n`, видимо гугловый вебсервер достаточно умный, чтобы такое обработать